# RAM usage on Mac

Tags: macos, memory

I have a Mac Pro tower, 12 cores, 64 GB memory, 1 TB, of which 750 GB free. I'm currently using a Mojave OS, 10.14. A soon as the system is running, it uses 10 GB of memory. Is this normal? I had the same problem when, on the same machine, I was using Sierra.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It's not a problem, it's a solution.

The machine won't hand back recently used memory in case it's needed again - because fetching it even from SSD is a thousand times slower than just grabbing it right from RAM.
it will only start to hand RAM back if it needs to - which on a 64GB machine isn't going to be often.

I have a similar machine [currently it gets rebooted a lot because of a new Mojave beta every week] so after 2 days of not doing much, it's using 30GB... lots left, no panic.

If you look at the memory pressure graph, bottom left of Activity Monitor [in Applications/Utilities, then Memory tab], so long as that's green, you have zero problems. Even orange & the Mac is handling things well. Only start to worry if it goes red & stays that way for more than a few seconds... though that would probably need you to be running Final Cut Pro on a huge movie compression ***and*** compiling a new app in Xcode at the same time ;)

Comment: Very clear, thank you very much! I'll keep an eye on the memory pressure graph :)